# When @Builder and @NoArgsConstructor are set, variables do not get initialized

Tags: lombok

Let's say there is a class A:

```
@Getter @Setter @Builder @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class A extends X implements Y, Z {

    private B b = new B();

    private List<C> cList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

When I create an object by calling `A a = new A();`, no variables get initialized, so `b` and `cList` are `null`.

If `@Builder` annotation is removed, it works.

I didn't find any solution in project lombok documentation.

What should I do to get them initialized?

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/pull/1429

"For now, the workaround is to type a no-args constructor and initialize the fields with the same expression in the constructor."

```
@Getter @Setter @Builder @AllArgsConstructor
public class A extends X implements Y, Z {

    private B b = new B();

    private List<C> cList = new ArrayList<>();

    public A() {
        b = new B();
        cList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```